# gear shifting after changing cassette

Tags: derailleur, cassette

I've just changed a worn out cassette on my road bike (SRAM 8 speed 12-26T) and replaced it with a Shimano 12-25T 8 speed cassette.  Now it looks like my gear shifting doesn't work.  I can't get into the lowest gear, and there's a clicking sound when I try.  I know almost nothing about derailleurs.  What is my best option now?

Comment: You probably need to rearrange your limit settings, you can have a look at [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8RbFE8yX7ww&feature=iv&src_vid=rpBP-UWVkXY&annotation_id=annotation_1504050971), if the limits are not set correctly the chain could either fall off the cassette when going up or not being able to reach the smaller cog when going down.

Comment: Do remember to check and adjust the limit on the other side of the cassette too - having the chain jump off the end is no fun either.

Comment: Ende, your comment should be posted as an answer.

Comment: @Carl I wasn't sure that was the actual solution, I wanted to wait until I had confirmation.

Comment: Also note that you should generally install a new chain when you install a new cassette.

Answer (score 1):

As I stated in my comment,you need to rearrange your limit settings after switching the cassette, you can have a look at [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8RbFE8yX7ww&feature=iv&src_vid=rpBP-UWVkXY&annotation_id=annotation_1504050971), if the limits are not set correctly the chain could either fall off the cassette or not being able to reach the smaller/bigger cog.